# Matrix to Diagonal Matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, diagonal

Let's say I have a matrix in MATLAB like

```
A = [1 2 3; 
     4 5 6; 
     7 8 9]
```

and I would like to obtain a matrix of the form

```
B = [1 0 0;  
     0 4 0; 
     0 0 7;
     2 0 0;
     0 5 0;
     0 0 8;
     3 0 0;
     0 6 0;
     0 0 9]
```

i.e. a matrix that is a concatenation of three diagonal matrices, with each having the columns of matrix `A` at their diagonals. I know how to do this using a `for` loop over the columns of `A` and then concatenating all the results but I am looking for a shorter way to do this. Please share your ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
B(repmat(eye(3),3,1)==1) = A;
reshape(B, [], 3)
```

Comment: It should be `repmat(eye(3),3,1)` I think...

Comment: @tmpearce yes I'll edit.

Comment: @Shai You do, otherwise it comes out as a vector

Comment: What if A was a matrix of dimensions (x,y)?

Comment: @Erol if x and y differ then you need to redefine your probelm, otherwise simply replace all the `3`s with `n` such that `n = size(A, 1)`

Comment: Thank you. I made it work for general cases.

Answer (score 3):

```
B = sparse( 1:numel(A), repmat( 1:size(A,2), [1 size(A,1)] ),...
            A(:), numel(A), size(A,2));
```

should do the trick.

You can `B = full(B);` if you want a full matrix

Comment: What if A was a matrix of dimensions (x,y)?

Comment: @Erol have you tried the code with arbitrary `A`? the solution should work as-is for any `A`.

Comment: Thank you. Yours works as well but I had to accept one so I went with the one easiest to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way using linear indexing:

```
B(sub2ind([9 3], 1:9, mod(0:8,3)+1))=A;
reshape(B,9,3)
```

If you want this to be generic, realize that each column of the original becomes a diagonal. Therefore, the number of rows in the original becomes the number of columns in the output, and 3 `rows x cols` becomes the number of rows. The rest of the answer doesn't change at all:

```
c = size(A,1);
r = size(A,1) * size(A,2); #% or prod(size(A));
B(sub2ind([r c], 1:r, mod(0:(r-1),c)+1)) = A;
```

Comment: What if A was a matrix of dimensions (x,y)?

Comment: @erol See edit: it generalizes easily

Comment: Thank you. Yours works as well but I had to accept one so I went with the one easiest to understand.